# Updating records within a modal

Tags: json, django, django-views, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

We have taken on a project where the front end admin dashboard has been created using Bootstrap Modals.

When we go to update a record from the ASP modal we have used JSON outputs and JQuery to populate the data within the form, as from what we found this could not be done by Django alone.

The issue we have is that we can add new records using the populated JSON data but I cannot edit existing records. Even though JQUERY and JSON brings the correct data when we click submit it cannot associate to the record within the database.

How could we update the correct record?

One other method we tried was passing the ID (related to the booking) through the URL but this kept redirecting the page and not staying on the modal.

Just so I don't add to much, below is the related code to the issue.

I am not great with programming so hope this makes some sense what we are trying to achieve, thanks in advance for any help we can get with this issue.

View Code

```
class admin_booking(View):
def get(self, request):

    # check whether the user is logged in.
    context = initialize_context(request)
    token = get_token(request)
    session = request.session
    if session.get('user') == None:
        return redirect('vistours:signin')

    # get the model data.
    asp_data = ASPBookings.objects.all()
    bfbw_data = BFBWBookings.objects.all()
    tour_data = SchoolTourBookings.objects.all()
    ath_data = Athlete.objects.all()

    # add the model data to a context dictionary
    context = {
        'asp_bookings': asp_data,
        'bfbw_bookings': bfbw_data,
        'tour_bookings': tour_data,
        'ath_data':ath_data,
        'ath_form': AthleteForm(),
        'asp_form': ASPBookingsForm(),
    }

    # Serialise the data to JSON output file.
    with open("vistours/static/vistours/json/asp.json", "w") as out:
        json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer('json')()
        json_serializer.serialize(asp_data, stream=out, indent=4)

    with open("vistours/static/vistours/json/bfbw.json", "w") as out:
        json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer('json')()
        json_serializer.serialize(bfbw_data, stream=out, indent=4)

    with open("vistours/static/vistours/json/tours.json", "w") as out:
        json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer('json')()
        json_serializer.serialize(tour_data, stream=out, indent=4)

    return render(request, 'vistours/admin_bookings.html', context)

    # post athlete data Modal.
def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AthleteForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            form()
        return redirect('vistours:admin_booking')    

    # Update ASP Modal.
def post(self, request, id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            asp_id = request.POST.get('booking_ref')
            asp_data = ASPBookings.objects.filter(id=id)
            print(asp_id)
            print(asp_data)
            form = ASPBookingsForm(request.POST)
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        return redirect('vistours:admin_booking')
```

URLS

```
path('admin_bookings/all/', views.admin_booking.as_view(), name='admin_booking'),
path('admin_bookings/confirmed/', views.admin_booking_confirmed.as_view(), name='admin_booking_confirmed'),
path('admin_bookings/tbc/', views.admin_booking_tbc.as_view(), name='admin_booking_tbc'),
path('admin_bookings/completed/', views.admin_booking_completed.as_view(), name='admin_booking_completed'),
path('admin_bookings/cancelled/', views.admin_booking_cancelled.as_view(), name='admin_booking_cancelled'),
```

Model

```
class ASPBookings(models.Model):

# Select/Choice field value lookups ('Database', 'HTML').

presentation_form_options = (
    ('Face to Face', 'Face to Face'),
    ('Virtual', 'Virtual'),
)
organisation_types = (
    ('Government School', 'Government School'),
    ('Community Organisation', 'Community Organisation'),
    ('Non-Government School', 'Non-Government School'),
    ('Other', 'Other')
)

regions = (
    ('Metro', 'Metro'),
    ('Regional', 'Regional')
)

statuses = (
    ('TBC', 'TBC'),
    ('Confirmed', 'Confirmed'),
    ('Completed', 'Completed'),
    ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled')

)

booking_times = [
    ('0900', '0900'),
    ('0915', '0930'),
    ('0930', '0900'),
    ('0945', '0945'),
    ('1000', '1000'),
    ('1015', '1030'),
    ('1030', '1000'),
    ('1045', '1045'),
    ('1100', '1100'),
    ('1115', '1130'),
    ('1130', '1100'),
    ('1145', '1145'),
    ('1200', '1200'),
    ('1215', '1230'),
    ('1230', '1200'),
    ('1245', '1245'),
    ('1300', '1300'),
    ('1315', '1330'),
    ('1330', '1300'),
    ('1345', '1345'),
    ('1400', '1400'),
    ('1415', '1430'),
    ('1430', '1400'),
    ('1445', '1445'),
    ('1500', '1500'),
]

durations = [
    ('0.5', '0.5'),
    ('1.0', '1.0'),
    ('1.5', '1.5'),
    ('2.0', '2.0'),
    ('2.5', '2.5'),
    ('3.0', '3.0'),
]

booking_ref = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=1)
program_type = models.CharField(max_length=120)
booking_date = models.DateField()
booking_time = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=booking_times, default='0700')
duration = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=durations, default='0.5')
street = models.CharField(max_length=120)
suburb = models.CharField(max_length=120)
region = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=regions, default='Metro')
post_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
organisation_type = models.CharField(max_length=120,choices=organisation_types, default='Government School')
audience_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
presentation_form = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=presentation_form_options, default='Face to Face')
contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
email = models.EmailField()
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=120)
comments = models.TextField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=statuses, default='TBC')
athlete = models.ForeignKey(Athlete, default= '1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.contact_name

# return URL after the POST has been submitted.
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('success')
```

Form

```
class ASPBookingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta():
    model = ASPBookings
    # Inclusion / Exclusion of fields within the Form view.
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['athlete', 'status']
    # Widgets add Bootstrap and CCS classes to Django inputs.
    widgets = {
        'booking_ref': TextInput(attrs={'id':'asp_booking_ref', 'name': 'asp_booking_ref'}),
        'program_type': TextInput(attrs={'id': 'asp_prev_program', 'name': 'prev_program'}),
        'booking_date': TextInput(attrs={'type':'date', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'asp_prev_date', 'name': 'prev_date'}),
        'booking_time': Select(attrs={'class':'form-select','id': 'asp_prev_time', 'name': 'prev_time'}),
        'duration': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select','id': 'asp_prev_duration', 'name': 'prev_duration'}),
        'street': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'asp_street', 'name': 'street', 'placeholder': 'Flinders Street'}),
        'suburb': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'asp_suburb', 'name': 'suburb', 'placeholder': 'Albert Park'}),
        'post_code': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'asp_postcode', 'name': 'postcode', 'placeholder': '3000'}),
        'region': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select', 'id': 'asp_region', 'asp_name': 'region', 'placeholder': 'region'}),
        'organisation_type': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select', 'id': 'asp_org_type', 'name': 'org_type', 'placeholder': 'Organisation Type'}),
        'audience_number': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'asp_audience_number', 'name': 'audience', 'placeholder': '0-999'}),
        'presentation_form': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select', 'id': 'asp_presentation_form', 'name': 'presentation_form'}),
        'contact_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'asp_contact_name', 'name': 'contact_name', 'placeholder': 'John Doe'}),
        'email': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'asp_email', 'name': 'email', 'placeholder': 'name@example.com'}),
        'phone_number': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'asp_phone', 'name': 'phone', 'placeholder': '0400 000 000', 'pattern': '^((\+61\s?)?(\((0|02|03|04|07|08)\))?)?\s?\d{1,4}\s?\d{1,4}\s?\d{0,4}$'}),
        'comments': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'asp_comments', 'name': 'comments'}),
    }
```

HTML

```
   <tbody>
            {% for booking in asp_bookings %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{booking.id}}</td>
              <td>{{booking.program_type}}</td>
              <td>{{booking.booking_date}}</td>
              <td>{{booking.booking_time}}</td>
              <td>{{booking.duration}}</td>
              <td>{{booking.organisation_type}}</td>
              <td>{{booking.contact_name}}</td>
              <td>
                <p class="table_tag">{{booking.athlete.athlete_name}}</p>
                <a href="#">
                  <i data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#assign_athlete_modal" class="fa fa-user-times table_icons mx-1">
                  </i>
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                {% if booking.status == "TBC"%}
                <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success table_tag">{{booking.status}}</span>
                {% elif booking.status == "Confirmed"%}
                <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary table_tag">{{booking.status}}</span>
                {% elif booking.status == "Cancelled"%}
                <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger table_tag">{{booking.status}}</span>
                {% else %}
                <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-secondary table_tag">{{booking.status}}</span>
                {% endif %}
                {% if booking.program_type == "asp" %}
                <a href="#"><i data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit_asp_modal" class="fa fa-pencil table_icons mx-1" data-vis-ref="{{booking.id}}" data-vis-program="{{booking.program_type}}"></i></a>
                {% elif booking.program_type == "bfbw" %}
                <a href="#"><i data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit_bfbw_modal" class="fa fa-pencil table_icons mx-1" data-vis-ref="{{booking.id}}" data-vis-program="{{booking.program_type}}"></i></a>
                {% elif booking.program_type == "tours" %}
                <a href="#"><i data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit_tours_modal" class="fa fa-pencil table_icons mx-1" data-vis-ref="{{booking.id}}" data-vis-program="{{booking.program_type}}"></i></a>
                {% endif %}
                {% if booking.status == "Confirmed" %}
                <a class="fa-disabled-admin-icons" href="{% url 'vistours:asp_confirm_booking' id=booking.id %}"><i class="fa fa fa-check table_icons mx-1"></i></a>
                <a href="{% url 'vistours:asp_cancel_booking' id=booking.id %}"><i class="fa fa-trash table_icons mx-1"></i></a>
                {% elif booking.status == "Cancelled" %}
                <a href="{% url 'vistours:asp_confirm_booking' id=booking.id %}"><i class="fa fa fa-check table_icons mx-1"></i></a>
                <a class="fa-disabled-admin-icons" href="{% url 'vistours:asp_cancel_booking' id=booking.id %}"><i class="fa fa-trash table_icons mx-1"></i></a>
                {% elif booking.status == "Completed" %}
                <a class="fa-disabled-admin-icons" href="{% url 'vistours:asp_confirm_booking' id=booking.id %}"><i class="fa fa fa-check table_icons mx-1"></i></a>
                <a href="{% url 'vistours:asp_cancel_booking' id=booking.id %}"><i class="fa fa-trash table_icons mx-1"></i></a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'vistours:asp_confirm_booking' id=booking.id %}"><i class="fa fa fa-check table_icons mx-1"></i></a>
                <a href="{% url 'vistours:asp_cancel_booking' id=booking.id %}"><i class="fa fa-trash table_icons mx-1"></i></a>
                {% endif %}

              </td>

 <!-- EDIT ASP Modal -->
  <form method="post" id="edit_asp_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    {{ form.source.errors }}
    {{ form.source }}
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit_asp_modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header card-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil mx-1"></i> Edit ASP Booking Details</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="card text-dark bg-light mb-3">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                  {{asp_form.street}}
                  <!-- <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="asp_edit_street" name="asp_edit_street" placeholder="Flinders Street"> -->
                  <label for="asp_edit_street">Street</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                  {{asp_form.suburb}}
                  <!-- <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="asp_edit_suburb" name="asp_edit_suburb" placeholder="Albert Park"> -->
                  <label for="asp_edit_suburb">Suburb</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                  {{asp_form.post_code}}
                <!-- <input required oninput="this.value =
                !!this.value && Math.abs(this.value) >= 0 ? Math.abs(this.value) : null;if(this.value<0){this.value= this.value =0} else if(this.value>9999){this.value= this.value =9999}
                " type="number" min="0" max="9999" class="form-control" name="asp_edit_postcode" id="asp_edit_postcode" placeholder="0 - 9999"> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_postcode">Post Code</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{asp_form.audience_number}}
                <!-- <input required oninput="this.value =
                !!this.value && Math.abs(this.value) >= 0 ? Math.abs(this.value) : null;if(this.value<0){this.value= this.value =0} else if(this.value>9999){this.value= this.value =9999}
                " type="number" min="0" max="9999" class="form-control" name="asp_edit_audience_number" id="asp_edit_audience_number" placeholder="0 - 9999"> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_audience_number">Audience Number</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{asp_form.region}}
                <!-- <select class="form-select" id="asp_edit_region" name="asp_edit_region">
                  <option value="1">Metro</option>
                  <option value="2" selected>Suburb</option>
                </select> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_region">Region</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{asp_form.organisation_type}}
                <!-- <select class="form-select" id="asp_edit_org_type" name="asp_edit_org_type">
                  <option value="1">Community organisation</option>
                  <option value="2">Corporation</option>
                  <option value="3" selected>Government school</option>
                  <option value="4">Non-Government school</option>
                  <option value="5">Other</option>
                </select> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_org_type">Organisation Type</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{asp_form.duration}}
                <!-- <select  class="form-select" id="asp_edit_session_length" name="asp_edit_session_length">
                  <option value="1">0.5 Hr</option>
                  <option value="2">1.0 Hr</option>
                  <option value="3">1.5 Hr</option>
                  <option value="4">2.0 Hr</option>
                  <option value="5">2.5 Hr</option>
                  <option value="6">3.0 Hr</option>
                </select> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_session_length">Session Length</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{asp_form.booking_time}}
                <!-- <select class="form-select" id="asp_edit_time" name="asp_edit_time">
                  <option selected value="0700">07:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="0715">07:15 AM</option>
                  <option value="0730">07:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="0745">07:45 AM</option>
                  <option value="0800">08:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="0815">08:15 AM</option>
                  <option value="0830">08:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="0845">08:45 AM</option>
                  <option value="0900">09:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="0915">09:15 AM</option>
                  <option value="0930">09:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="0945">09:45 AM</option>
                  <option value="1000">10:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="1015">10:15 AM</option>
                  <option value="1030">10:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="1045">10:45 AM</option>
                  <option value="1100">11:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="1115">11:15 AM</option>
                  <option value="1130">11:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="1145">11:45 AM</option>
                  <option value="1200">12:00 Noon</option>
                  <option value="1215">12:15 PM</option>
                  <option value="1230">12:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="1245">12:45 PM</option>
                  <option value="1300">01:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="1315">01:15 PM</option>
                  <option value="1330">01:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="1345">01:45 PM</option>
                  <option value="1400">02:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="1415">02:15 PM</option>
                  <option value="1430">02:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="1445">02:45 PM</option>
                  <option value="1500">03:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="1515">03:15 PM</option>
                  <option value="1530">03:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="1545">03:45 PM</option>
                  <option value="1600">04:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="1615">04:15 PM</option>
                  <option value="1630">04:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="1645">04:45 PM</option>
                  <option value="1700">05:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="1715">05:15 PM</option>
                  <option value="1730">05:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="1745">05:45 PM</option>
                  <option value="1800">06:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="1815">06:15 PM</option>
                  <option value="1830">06:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="1845">06:45 PM</option>
                  <option value="1900">07:00 PM</option>
                </select> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_time">From 07:00 AM to 07:00 PM</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating">
                {{asp_form.booking_date}}
                <!-- <input required type="date" class="form-control" id="asp_edit_date" name="asp_edit_date"> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_date">Date</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card text-dark bg-light mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{asp_form.presentation_form}}
                <!-- <select class="form-select" id="asp_edit_presentation_form" name="asp_edit_presentation_form">
                  <option value="1" selected>Face-to-Face</option>
                  <option value="2">Virtual</option>
                </select> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_presentation_form">Preferred Presentation Form</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{asp_form.contact_name}}
                <!-- <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="asp_edit_contact_name" name="asp_edit_contact_name" placeholder="John Doe"> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_contact_name">Contact Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{asp_form.email}}
                <!-- <input required type="email" class="form-control" id="asp_edit_email" name="asp_edit_email" placeholder="name@example.com"> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_email">Email</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{asp_form.phone_number}}
                <!-- <input pattern="^((\+61\s?)?(\((0|02|03|04|07|08)\))?)?\s?\d{1,4}\s?\d{1,4}\s?\d{0,4}$" required type="text" class="form-control" id="asp_edit_phone" name="asp_edit_phone" placeholder="0400 000 000"> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_phone">Phone</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating">
                {{asp_form.comments}}
                <!-- <textarea required class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment here" name="asp_edit_comments" id="asp_edit_comments" maxlength="500"></textarea> -->
                <label for="asp_edit_comments">Speaker Brief</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{asp_form.program_type}}
        {{asp_form.booking_ref}}
        
        <!-- <input type="text" name="asp_edit_program" id="asp_prev_program" hidden="hidden" style="visibility: hidden;"> -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save_edit_asp">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- END EDIT ASP Modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this can help anyone else, I manage to fix the modal to allow updates by changing the Post view to below.

```
 def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            booking_id = request.POST.get('booking_ref')
            asp_data = ASPBookings.objects.get(id=booking_id)
            asp_data.street = request.POST['street']
            asp_data.suburb = request.POST['suburb']
            asp_data.post_code = request.POST['post_code']
            asp_data.audience_number = request.POST['audience_number']
            asp_data.region = request.POST['region']
            asp_data.organisation_type = request.POST['organisation_type']
            asp_data.duration = request.POST['duration']
            asp_data.booking_time = request.POST['booking_time']
            asp_data.booking_date = request.POST['booking_date']
            asp_data.presentation_form = request.POST['presentation_form']
            asp_data.contact_name = request.POST['contact_name']
            asp_data.email = request.POST['email']
            asp_data.phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']
            asp_data.comments = request.POST['comments']
            asp_data.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        return redirect('vistours:admin_booking')
```